# DateTime error with Caml Query?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, caml-query

I have created a column in SharePoint named `Data e skadimit të kontrates` and I am trying to query this column with the following query:

```
queryMuaj.Query = @"<Where><Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name='Data e skadimit të kontrates' />
                 <Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
              </Eq></Where>";
```

but it shows me a masive error like this:

[image]

Comment: The internal field name is wrong, it isn't going to have spaces in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CAML Query you should use field internal name instead of Display Name.

You can get the internal name for a column by browsing to the `List Settings` > `Edit Column` and look at the QueryString value `Field`.

Comment: for example is this an internal name: `Data_x0020_e_x0020_skadimit_x002` ? i am getting it on link

Comment: YEs that is the name you should use

Comment: I love you it worked